# PDO code completion in IDEA

Tags: php, pdo, intellij-idea

I get code completion for the PDO:: constants, but not PDO's methods, such as:

```
class Database {
  public function connect() {
    $this->dbh = new PDO(...);
    return $this->dbh;
  }
}

...

$dbh = $db->connect();
$dbh->{CODE COMPLETION WANTED HERE}
```

Any tricks to letting IDEA know what type $dbh is?

**Update:**

After IDEA's cache is invalidated `File|Invalidate Caches`, PDO code completion starts to work, but as soon as the indexes have finished regenerating, it stops again.

Comment: For closer: "software tools commonly used by programmers": tick; minimal understanding of problem shown: tick. Research done: about 30 minutes, tick; solutions tried: n/a.